# Publish my webapi project aspnet web api angularjs

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

I want to publish my project to a folder in IIS but with the routes setup the way it is I get what looks like an internal loop and not finding the path.

[image]

I published the project in a folder already

```
angular.module("common.services", ["ngResource"])

.constant("appSettings",
{
    //serverPath: "http://localhost:53967/"
    //name of the computer and folder to which the project was published
    serverPath:"http://ct-dx-ariang/AspNetWebApi/"
});
```

And have a resource setup as follow

```
 angular.module("common.services").factory("productResource", ["$resource", "appSettings", productResource])

function productResource($resource, appSettings) {

    //return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:search");
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:id"
```

These are my routes

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");//default url
        $stateProvider.state("home", {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "/templates/welcomeView.html"
        }).state("productList", {
            url: "/products",
            templateUrl: "/templates/productListView.html",
            controller: "ProductListController"
        }).
```

How can I modify this sample project so that it runs in the published folder on the IIS as opposed to in localhost on visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slash at the beginning of a path makes that path relative to the root of the site. So in your case:

```
templateUrl: "/templates/productListView.html"
```

will always refer to `http://myhostname/templates/productListView.html`, no matter in which subpath is hosted your site.

Removing the first slash may solve your issue:

```
templateUrl: "templates/productListView.html"
```

---

Also looking at your `$resource` configuration:

```
return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:id"
```

And your `AppSettings` constant:

```
serverPath:"http://ct-dx-ariang/AspNetWebApi/"
```

Seems to me that you are adding two consecutive slashes to your `$resource` path. The resulting path will be: `http://ct-dx-ariang/AspNetWebApi//api/products/:id`

Answer (score 1):

> These are my routes

Pretty hardcoded. Make sure that you use the same constant over there for all your templates as well.

```
templateUrl: appSettings.serverPath + "/templates/welcomeView.html"
```